# Checking deb dependencies against the current system

Tags: debian, dependencies, packages

I know I can list the `.deb`'s dependencies using `dpkg --info`, but is there any automated way to check those dependencies against the current system? What I'm interested in, the status: whether the package will be cleanly installed, or will it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual: `dpkg -i --force-bad-path --dry-run foo.deb`. However, it doesn't work, [a bug was filed about this 10 years ago](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=55364).

There is a corresponding option in `apt-get` and `aptitude`, but that only applies to packages obtained via apt.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way which is very hackish but does work, sort of.

Make sure you're not root, or you risk overwriting some system files.
Create a temporary directory and change to it.

```
mkdir root
cp -as /var/lib/dpkg .
rm dpkg/lock dpkg/triggers/Lock
fakeroot dpkg --force-not-root --force-bad-path --admindir=dpkg --instdir=root --log=log -i mypackage.deb
```

This will unpack the package and then complain about any missing dependencies on stderr. It's likely to return a nonzero status even if there are no missing dependencies because of a failing `postinst` script.

I haven't tried with a package that has a `preinst` script, it's possible that `dpkg` will give up before checking dependencies.

Comment: Try #3... This time, I tested it (on lenny).